# Error: Bad arguments: First argument should be a string, second should be an array of strings

Tags: javascript, discord.js

main file

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const stringSimilarity = require("string-similarity");
const pokemons = require('../../arrays/pokemons.js')
const poss = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(args, pokemons)
console.log(poss.bestMatch.target)
```

arrays file

```js
exports.pokemons = [
    example1,
    example2,
    example3,
    etc...
]
```

I am trying to get the closest name for the pokemon that the user inputs but I get this error `Error: Bad arguments: First argument should be a string, second should be an array of strings` and I am pretty sure that I did the arguments correct

Comment: What's the message being sent, and what do you want to be the match?

Comment: so if  i typed for example chariza I want it to look in the file pokemons.js and find the closest match so it will be charizard and I have a long list of every pokemon in that file but its says bad arguments

Comment: I mean what is the message (including the prefix and args)

Comment: this will just get the message content but exclude prefix which is `?` and the `command` name after it so it will be just the message content as a string and if I typed the code like this `const poss = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(args, ['what', 'hello', 'yes'])` it works but because its in a different file it doesn't work

Comment: What is the *message* though? What exactly do you send?

Comment: the message content on discord I am sorry but I am confused about what you are saying

Comment: I am asking what message you send on discord, including the prefix, command and arguments... was it not clear?

Comment: oh ?pokedex charizard <-- string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first is that you are exporting the array file as an object. This is what `pokemons` really is, since you set it as `exports.pokemons`:

```js
{
  pokemons: [
    example1,
    example2
  ]
}
```

You can destructure it:

```js
const { pokemons } = require('../../arrays/pokemons.js')
```

And the second problem is that you are passing in the array of arguments. You probably just want the first argument. Remember arrays are 0-indexed and you made it start with the command so you have to get index `1` for the first argument

```js
const poss = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(args[1], pokemons)
```

Comment: i still have the same error

Comment: You destructured it and accessed the argument?

Comment: yes this is what i did `{
    pokemons: [
        "Bulbasaur",
        "Ivysaur",
        "Venusaur"
]
} and in main file const { pokemons } = require('../../arrays/pokemons.js')

Comment: Don't change the array file, only the main file. I just showed what `pokemons` actually was

Comment: the same error i just changed the main file as you said

Comment: Would you like to continue this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239363)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239364/discussion-between-dancing-potato-and-mrmythical).

Answer (score 0):

As the error said that the `findBestMatch` is defined where first element is a `string`, but the `args` is surely array. Check your `findBestMatch` params again.

Comment: no the args is a string the problem is with pokemons which is supposed to be an array but it wont read it as an array

Comment: The `args` ends with `.split(/ +/);`, it's supposed to be an array btw

Comment: well if i typed it as this `const poss = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(args, ['what', 'hello', 'yes'])` it works fine but when i typed it like this `const poss = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(args, pokemons)` it doesnt work so the problem isn't with args